# How to get number of pages printed when using print document control?

Tags: vb.net

Well, as the title says, I want to get the total count of pages printed after the user sends the order. That's because I have a database where I need to store the sale like "A4 COLOR(or black&white)/ 45 pages". I care about the number of pages but I dont know if is possible to get the color mode info too. Thanks for any help

Comment: There is no print document control. A control is a class that inherits, directly or indirectly, the `Control` class. `Control` appears nowhere in the inheritance chain of the `PrintDocument` class.  `PrintDocument` is a component, which is all that's required to be used in the WinForms designer.

Comment: The number of pages that were or are going to be printed is not something that is stored within a `PrintDocument` object. A page is printed each time the `PrintPage` event is raised so, if you want the number of pages printed, you need to increment a counter each time that event is raised.

Comment: The alternative would be to do all your calculations in the `BeginPrint` event handler.  For instance, if you were printing records and you knew how many records there were to print and how many were to be printed per page, you would know how many pages there were going to be before doing any printing.